# Advantages of IoC and DI in web applications

Tags: spring-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I am studying dependency injection and inversion of control from a manning book, as far as i have understood from the examples, IoC can be applied at application initialisation time.
When the application starts it reads the xml spring config file and initialises the beans with their dependencies.
I understand the advantages of this, mainly the testability of completely loose classes is a great advantage.
What i would like to understand is how to apply IoC and DI on a mvc-based web application, i have built a simple web application in SpringMVC (i normally develop using Stripes), but i cant see how i can take advantage of IoC and DI in a web application flow, where the user navigates through the site, inserts comments, submit forms, upload files for the backend to read them and return some results, fetches data from the DB. 
All those actions are of course performed after the application is initialised (in the web server), and where IoC has already been applied.
So i am trying to understand if it is really worth to learn it.
Any advise/hint/comment/link is appreciated

Comment: which manning book are you reading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an MVC application you will have some layers. You have views, controllers and model but in some cases you will also have a business layer and a data access layer.

My recommendation is that you separate your project so each of this layers its compiled into its own .jar file (or .dll file if you are working on .Net). Then you need to keep an eye for references from one of the jar files to another. References are a bad sign because they mean that your layers are coupled.

So how do you keep your layers independent of each other? You need to declare the public interface of each of your layers. If a layer needs another layer (dependency) you will not add a reference to the dependency, instead you need to depend upon its interface.

The layers communicate with each other sending POCOs. Plain objects that contain data but does not contain behavior. These plain objects are just classes and are not tightly coupled to a framework.

We do this because it help us to keep concrete technologies encapsulated within a layer. For example you could use hibernate in your data access layer but you want to keep hibernate inside your data access layer. Your controllers and business layer don't need to know which data access technology do you use. This will allow you to replace your technologies for more modern technologies in the future without having to replace your entire application.

When you are writing the code and compiling the code your layers should know nothing about other layers. The only thing that they should be aware of is their interfaces. At runtime, the IoC containers will create instances of the dependencies and inject them in the right place.

- User submits a form
- The router identifies the required controller
- The IoC container creates an instance of the controller
- The controller deals with HTTP stuff, it parses the user input and creates a POCO object which is then passed to the business layer (BL). The controller knows about the business layer interface but not the concrete implementation.
- The business layers transfer the POCO to a few services in the Data access layer (DAL)
- The business layers knows about the DAL interface but not the concrete implementation or concrete technologies used for data storage.
- Both the DAL and BL were injected by the IoC container at runtime. This allows the layers to avoid references to each other.

Dependency inversion helps you to separate concerns but on its own is not a big deal and it may lead you to think that is not worth it. Learning DI is the first step but you also need to take a look to the other 4 SOLID principles and architectures that take advantage of DI.

One of them is the Onion Architecture:

[image]

You can learn more about it at:

http://blog.thedigitalgroup.com/chetanv/2015/07/06/understanding-onion-architecture/

I would recommend you to read:

- [Dependency Injection in .NET](https://www.manning.com/books/dependency-injection-in-dot-net)
- [Patterns, Principles, and Practices of Domain-Driven Design](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Patterns-Principles-and-Practices-of-Domain-Driven-Design.productCd-1118714709.html)